# Deploying shiny app -> dependencies in this file will not be discovered

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I know I'm not the only one with this problem but I have tried several solutions and nothing has worked yet. When I'm deploying my shinyapp (that works perfectly on Windows 11 and 10) i get this warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In fileDependencies.R(file) :
  Failed to parse C:/Users/nicol/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQF8uhX/file438c489067a3/app.R ; dependencies in this file will not be discovered.
```

I have tried saving my app as a UTF-8 file (there are German Umlauts in it) in RStudio and I have tried to use this as the first line of my code:

```
options(encoding = "UTF-8")
```

I deploy on the Rstuido GUI. Maybe that's the problem. But I don't understand how to deploy through the commandline.

Thx for your help

Comment: Where should you app live once it is deployed? I think you need usually `fileDependencies.R` only if your app should be deployed in the shinyapps.io cloud

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to deploy it to shinyapps.io

Comment: Then I can not help you. Sorry, I've never used that cloud for deployments.

Comment: do you have a better suggestion for a place to deploy? I was thinking of setting up my Raspberry Pi as a server but that means a lot of extra trouble...

Comment: depends on how many users must use the app simultaneously. Shiny apps are very hard to scale e.g. you need to add a load balancer manually (e.g. shinyproxy). Raspis are only for testing and not designed for reliable production deployments. If you are not a sysadmin and if you need a reliable and scalable deployment environment, shiny apps.io  is the easiest option.

Comment: That's what I thought. (But I still love the Idea of everyone checking out an dashboard that runs on a tiny computer in my moms appartment =))

Comment: Raspis are cheaper than permanently running e.g. an AWS micro instance. shinyapps.io is the 'serverless' approach, so you do not need to install other software rather than your R code. It's your decision on how much money and time you spend for accessibility and speed.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. You have to deploy your app through the commandline and use this:

```
tmp.enc <- options()$encoding
options(encoding = "UTF-8")
rsconnect:: deployApp()
```

This can be a bit complicated because you can't chose from the GUI what you want to upload to shinymaps.io but at least it works.